# how to check if string contains all the characters from a to z?

Tags: php, regex

**Input is :**

```
wyyga
qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm
ejuxggfsts
```

**Output Should be:**

```
NO
YES
NO
```

Comment: Not a job for regex. Solution exists but is extremely inefficient. Use an array/bitset and scan through the string instead.

Comment: [`count_chars()`](http://php.net/count_chars) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*g)...and so on.....till (?=.*y)(?=.*z)[a-z]+$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dL7oF8/3

Comment: And this is the solution that I said exists, but inefficient. It is equal to calling string.indexOf(character) 26 times.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes but using regex cant think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

You Try This

```
 ^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*g)(?=.*h)(?=.*i)(?=.*j)(?=.*k)(?=.*l)(?=.*m)(?=.*n)(?=.*o)(?=.*p)(?=.*q)(?=.*r)(?=.*s)(?=.*t)(?=.*u)(?=.*v)(?=.*w)(?=.*x)(?=.*y)(?=.*z)[a-z]+$
```

- It will work as a regular expression
- if any problem with answer please comment me